# How to use an initialization list to call a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, console-application, call, shapes

Hello I am rather new to C++ and looking to call the `Rectangle` constructor from the `Square` constructor using an initialization list, in order to assign values to `sideA` and `sideB` of the square. Any advice will be appreciated.

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle (int a, int b);

    // ...

public:
    int sideA;
    int sideB;
};

Rectangle::Rectangle (int a, int b) {
    sideA = a;
    sideB = b;

    if (a < 1)
        sideA = 1;
    if (b < 1)
        sideB = 1;
}

class Square: public Rectangle
{
public:
    Square(int); //constructor
    void setSideA(int);
    void setSideB(int);
};

Square::Square (int a) {
    sideA = a;
    sideB = a;
}

void Square::setSideA(int a) {
    sideA = a;
    sideB = a;
    if (a < 1)
        sideA = 1;
        sideB = 1;
}

void Square::setSideB(int b) {
    sideA = b;
    sideB = b;
    if (b < 1)
        sideA = 1;
        sideB = 1;
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 I will keep that in mind next time I have a question

Comment: I assume you mean something like this: `Square::Square(int i) : Rectangle(i, i) {}`

Comment: See [square–rectangle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle%E2%80%93ellipse_problem).

Comment: [OT]: You need `{ }` for `if`, provided indentation doesn't match how it is really parsed.

Comment: @jkb Hey, this code does seem to have no errors. However, I am a little confused on why this works? In your comment "a" is the parameter for Square and Rectangle. I know for Square I need a value for each side of the square but I also need to assign values for Rectangle as well. I apologize s my comment is a bit meandering I am trying to be as clear as possible.

Comment: Well, `Square::Square(int i)` is obviously the constructor; the following colon introduces the initialization list; in the initialization list you can call a base class constructor, in this case passing `i` (or in your case `a`) for both sides of the Rectangle; the final `{}` is simply the empty body of the `Square` constructor since you don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the base class (`Rectangle`) constructor in the initializer list part of the derived class (`Square`) constructor, thus initializing the "base component" of the derived class in the same way as you can initialize data members (as shown in the initializer list for the `Rectangle` constructor in the below code):

```cpp
class Rectangle {
private:
    int sideA, sideB;
public:
    Rectangle(int a, int b) : sideA{ std::max(1,a) }, sideB{ std::max(1,b) } {} // Initialize data
    //...
};

class Square : public Rectangle {
public:
    Square(int s) : Rectangle{ s, s } {} // 'Initializer list' calls base class c'tor
    //...
};
```

Comment: I got an error thrown with initializer list but this worked Square: :Square(int s) : Rectangle(s, s) {}

Comment: @m24 You'll need `#include <algorithm>` for the definition of `std::max` ... is that the issue?

Comment: @m24 But I'm now curious. What was the error you got using the `Rectangle{ s, s }` syntax?

Comment: It was not Rectangle{ s, s } that threw me an error it was Square(int s) : and the error said "expected identifier

Comment: I do not know if I was supposed to assume the Square:: part of the Square:: Square(int s) : Rectangle{ s, s } {} ?

Comment: @m24 OK, I understand. You have your constructor *definition* outside the class body. But, unless it does something more than just set those member variables, you're likely better off keeping it inside the class, as I have shown. But it's really up to you.

Comment: ... when the definition is provide along with the *declaration* (i.e. in the class body, as in my code), the `Square::` part should not be used. When the definition is separate (as in your code), then it is needed.

Comment: Ah I see where you are coming from! I get a little hyper focused on a line of code at times and forget to look at other aspects when people give me advise. Either way thank you for very much for answering I really do appreciate it.